# A question about a positive continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Suppose $f \in C[0, 1]$ satisfies following properties:
>
> 1)$f(0) = f(1) = 0$
>
> 2)$\forall x \in (0, 1)$ $f(x) > 0$
>
> Do there always exist such $c$ and $d$ in $(0, 1)$ that $f(c) = f(d) = d - c$?

I  have tried to consider the function $g(x) = \max\{t \in [0, 1]|f(t) = f(x)\} - x - f(x)$ which is strictly positive in $0$ and negative in the point of largest point of maximum. Thus if that function were always continuous, our problem would have been solved. Unfortunately, it isn’t.

Comment: I think not, but I am not sure of a counterexample at the moment.

Comment: If you don't require $c$ and $d$ to differ, $c=d=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @lessili, initially, I wanted to ask the question about $[a, b]$, but then I saw, tat all we need is to prove this for $[0; 1]$ as any function can be "scaled" that way without losing the corresponding properties. Unfortunately, I forgot to edit $a$ and $b$ out from the first sentence. Now I corrected my mistake.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for pointing out another my mistake. $c$ and $d$ were from an open interval, not from a closed one.

Comment: This sure feels as if it's gonna be most easily solved by doing a bordism or homology argument on $I \times I$, but I don't see exactly how quite yet.

Comment: This is a particular case of [Toeplitz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular case of [Toeplitz's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem), which if the argument below is correct, is way simpler than the cases in which the conjecture is known to be true. the conjecture asks for the existence of a non-degenerate square inscribed in any simple closed curve of the plane.

In our case the simple closed curve is formed by the graph of the function $f$ and the segment $[0,1]\times \{0\}$.

---

Let's extend $f(x)$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ by defining it to be $0$ outside of $[0,1]$.

Define $g(x)=f(x+f(x))-f(x)$.

The function $g$ is continuous, since it is a composition of continuous functions.

It satisfies that $g(0)=f(f(0))-f(0)=0$ and $g(1)=f(1+f(1))-f(1)=f(1)-f(1)=0$.

Observe that also, if $x\in (0,1)$ and $x+f(x)\notin[0,1]$, then $g(x)\neq0$.

Therefore, if for some $x\in(0,1)$ we have $g(x)=0$, then $x+f(x)\in(0,1)$ and the points $c=x, d=x+f(x)$ satisfy that $f(c)=f(d)=d-c$.

---

To get a contradiction, assume that $g(x)>0$ on $(0,1)$.

Let $x_0\in(0,1)$ be the supremum of the points in which $f$ attains its maximum. Note that the set where $f$ attains its maximum is compact and contained in $(0,1)$.

Then $g(x_0)>0$ implies that $f(x_0+f(x_0))>f(x_0)>0$. Therefore, $x_0+f(x_0)\in(0,1)$ and $f$ attains on it a larger value than that on $x_0$. This is a contradiction. Therefore we cannot have $g(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

---

Assume now that $g(x)<0$ for $x\in (0,1)$.

Pick any point $x_0\in (0,1)$. And without loss of generality we can assume that $x_0$ is the infimum of $\{x\in[0,1]:\ f(x)=f(x_0)\}\subset (0,1)$. By assumption $g(x_0)<0$ and therefore $f(x_0+f(x_0))<f(x_0)$.

Consider the set $K_0=\{x\in[0,1]:\ x+f(x)\geq x_0\}$. This set is non-empty (contains $x_0$) compact, contained in $(0,1)$. Observe that it must contain some points $<x_0$, otherwise it will force $f(x_0)=0$, which is not allowed.

Let $x_1=\inf K_0<x_0$. Then $x_1+f(x_1)=x_0$. Since $g(x_1)<0$ we have that $f(x_0)=f(x_1+f(x_1))<f(x_1)$. But then, by continuity, there must be a point in $(0,x_1)$ where $f$ takes the value $f(x_0)$. This is a contradiction with the choice of $x_0$.

---

Since assuming $g(x)>0$ on $(0,1)$ and assuming $g(x)<0$ on $(0,1)$ are both impossible, we must have $g(x)=0$ for some point in $c\in(0,1)$. Then define $d=c+f(c)$ and we will have $f(c)=f(d)=d-c$.